# Python yahoo finance scraping stocks all work but one

Tags: python, web-scraping, yahoo-finance

I try to scrape stockprices on yahoo finance and the piece of code works on alot of stock tickers but stock ticker "ISPA.DE" does not work for some reason. it gives AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def stockprice(stock_ticker):
    url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" + str(stock_ticker) + "?p=" + str(stock_ticker) + "&.tsrc=fin-srch"
    print(url)
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

    price = soup.find('fin-streamer', {"class": 'Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)'}).text
    print(price)

stockprice("ISPA.DE")
```

I tried several ways but with no result. Other tickers do work...

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `User-Agent` HTTP header in request:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def stockprice(stock_ticker):
    url = (
        "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"
        + str(stock_ticker)
        + "?p="
        + str(stock_ticker)
        + "&.tsrc=fin-srch"
    )
    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:122.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/122.0"
    }

    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    price = soup.find("fin-streamer", {"class": "Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)"}).text
    print(price)


stockprice("ISPA.DE")
```

Prints:

```
26.63
```

Comment: Dear Andrej - just awesome. i am deeply impressed. BTW i am currently struggling to reproduce a solution you gave here - in thread: 62313432 - well i am trying to reproduce in thread: 77978889 : note: i just have issues with Beautiful Soup Links - href returns no results: i tried out several methods, techniques and ideas. Do you have any idea to get something working - either on google-colab or on a pycharm that is installed locally - look forward to hear from you - thanks in advance - ;)